# Macro to search for a text on the excel file with few tabs and create a new file with the search match

Tags: vba, excel, search

I have a excel file with multiple tabs.

I need to create a macro that will search in all tab and create a new file with all the search match.

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: can you explain what you tried so far or what exactly your problem is?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I just want to create a excel macro that search for a "word" and if the search find it, the macro will create a new file with all the positive results found from the search.

Comment: Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

see the code below if it can help to to start. I do not know what you want to do with the value found.

```
Option Explicit

Sub find()

Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim myValue As Variant
Dim Rng As Range
Dim wkb As Workbook
Dim lastrow As Long


WS_Count = Worksheets.Count


myValue = InputBox("Please enter the value that you want to look for:")


For i = 1 To WS_Count

        With Worksheets(i).UsedRange

            Set Rng = .find(What:=myValue)



                If Not Rng Is Nothing Then

                    MsgBox ("The value" & " " & myValue & " " & "found in" & " " & ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name & " " & Rng.Address)
                    'do whatever you want with the string found...



                Else

                    MsgBox ("Nothing found in" & " " & ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name)

           End If

        End With

    Next i


End Sub
```